# Canceling ajax request causes rails to throw exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, exception, autocomplete

I'm new to rails and i was looking for answer whole day. Lest's start from begginging.

UI: I have autocomplete (to be exact, YUI autocompleter on page).

```js
Y.one('input.search-from').plug(Y.Plugin.AutoComplete, {      
    resultHighlighter: 'phraseMatch',
    source: "/api/open_maps/search/{query}", 
    resultTextLocator: 'display_name'
}
```

where "/api/open_maps/search/{query}" goes to rails wich in my case is hired as a proxy to workaround same origin policy for ajax.

```rb
def search
  uri = URI.parse(searchUrl(CGI.escape(params[:query])))
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  response = http.request(request)
  render :json => response.body
end
```

If I type quickly all but last ajax requests from autocompleter to rails are cancelled, which make sense as we don't need them anymore. The problem is that rails is throwing ugly exceptions for all canceled requests:

```
Started GET "/api/open_maps/search/Den" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun May 06    04:20:03 +0100 2012
[2012-05-06 04:20:03] ERROR Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpresponse.rb:324:in `write'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpresponse.rb:324:in `<<'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpresponse.rb:324:in `_write_data'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpresponse.rb:296:in `send_body_string'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpresponse.rb:187:in `send_body'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpresponse.rb:104:in `send_response'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:79:in `run'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:55
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6
```

Additionally it looks like ruby is making cancelled requests in background anyway (that slows down everything).

My Q are:

1. How can we detect in rails that connection from Client failed / was cancelled?
2. Once we know about #1, how can we cancel request made by Net::HTTP?

I tried begin -> rescue -> end block to at least squash exception but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the trace, the error doesn't originate within Net::HTTP, which is why your `rescue` attempt didn't help.  The error is thrown when webrick tries to write the rack response back to the browser.

Your issue might be resolved by installing [mongrel](http://rubygems.org/gems/mongrel), [thin](http://rubygems.org/gems/thin) or [unicorn](http://rubygems.org/gems/unicorn) as your webserver.  Webrick is built-in to Ruby but is known to be Not Robust.